# Prevent selected row from refreshing in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, logic, selecteditem

I am using DataGrid for my application and I am using timer to update the datagrid from Database. The timer refreshes every 5 sec to see if there is new data. If there is any new data it updates in the datagrid. But it also resets everything in the datagrid and i loose selected index.

How do i prevent the selected item from updating or changing while other rows updates??

[DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEAWm.jpg)

```
public void InitTimer()
{
    Timer timer1 =  new Timer();
    timer1.Elapsed += Timer1_Elapsed;
    timer1.Interval = 5000; // in milliseconds
    timer1.Start();
}

private void Timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = AddData(dataGrid1);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any information how you are refreshing the `datagrid` with your timer? Do you use a ViewModel-Binding? It sounds like you update your data in your view (= code-behind). We need more info. Thank you

Comment: Hi Wolle,
I have updated the question with my timer function that i am using to update the datagrid.

Comment: Since other people may face the same problem, I must inform you that what you try to achieve is very bad practice in terms of good WPF programming style. I would advice you to choose a [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx) approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already wrote in my comment that I would highly advice against manipulating your [ItemsSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.itemssource.aspx) in your code-behind file (.xaml.cs) of your view.

Nevertheless I try to help you with your problem:

The problem you describe occurs because of setting the `ItemsSource` property each tick of the timer. Maybe something like this could work:

```
// This is the collection to bind your datagrid to
public ObservableCollection<YourObject> Data { get; } = new ObservableCollection<YourObject>();

// This method needs to be called once (preferably in the constructor)
private void InitDataGrid() 
{
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = this.Data;
}

private void Timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        // Here you need to call a method which modifies the Data property.
        // Try removing, inserting, updating the items directly to the collection.
        // Do not set the ItemsSource directly, instead manipulate the ObservableCollection.
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save the index before you re-set the `ItemsSource` and then set it back afterwards:

```
private void Timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        int index = dataGrid1.SelectedIndex;
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = AddData(dataGrid1);
        dataGrid1.SelectedIndex = index;
    }));
}
```